# text animation - "typing" text for the initial value in a text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a custom animation that will take the desired initial value of a text - and animate it so it looks like its being typed.

Like a search field - "Start here..."

```
function typeAnimation(val){
  let valArray = val.split('');

  console.log("valArray", valArray);
  console.log("val", val);


  let newChar = "";
  var i = 0;
  function display() {
    if(i < valArray.length) {
      console.log("valArray[i]", valArray[i]);

      newChar += valArray[i];
      i++;

      setTimeout(display, 100);

      console.log("newChar", newChar);
      return newChar;
    }
  };

  display()
}

initialSearchFormValues.search_term = typeAnimation(initialSearchFormValues.search_term);
```

this is what I've made - but the text doesn't update and the returned value appears empty in the field

latest example
http://jsfiddle.net/ojnfL1hs/2/

I need it to be something like a tween

```
var self = this;
var newText = "hellob"//d.value;
var textLength = newText.length;
return function(t) {
    self.textContent = newText.slice(0, Math.round(t * textLength));
};
```

Comment: This is tagged as reactjs, but I don't see any React code. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: well - it will go into a redux form - where it will need to set the initial value again - but I wanted to get this returning and char update function correct

Comment: It's not really clear what's supposed to be happening. The parent function logs some stuff to the console on a timer and returns `undefined` because it has no `return` statement. What do you need it to return?

Comment: want it to return part of initial value in steps -- so it looks like someone is typing

Comment: So... You want it to return an iterator? Or return a function that updates a callback with the new value of the string at a given interval? Or a chain of promises that can be iterated over?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ojnfL1hs/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me - these two functions.

```
  sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  async typeAnimation(text, timing, callback) {
    let concatStr = "";
    for (const char of text) {
        concatStr += char;
        await this.sleep(timing);
        callback(concatStr);
    }  
  }
```

and then in the react constructor

```
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {open: false, initial_search_term: {"search_term": "Start typing..."}};

    var self = this;
    this.typeAnimation(this.state.initial_search_term.search_term, 100, function(msg){
      self.setState({
        initial_search_term: {"search_term": msg}
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any deep nesting of components here... Or did you just mean the variable is nested within a state object? Anyway, glad you got it working ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: yeah but - its this bit - that allows the typing parts - the form part is deeply nested - its using the redux-forms and material ui framework

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that returns an async iterable. This can then be consumed in an async function with `for await (... of ...)`.

```js
const sleep = timing =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timing))

const typeAnimation = (text, timing) => ({
    async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        let concatStr = ''

        yield concatStr

        for (const char of text) {
            await sleep(timing)

            yield (concatStr = concatStr + char)
        }

        await sleep(timing)
    }
})

const animation = typeAnimation('Start typing...', 100)

;(async () => {
    // consumed like this
    for await (const str of animation) {
        document.querySelector('input').value = str
        // in React, you'd use something like
        // setStr(str) or setState({ str }) here
    }
})()
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: I need to kind of push it back into a variable -- then ref select an input like this -- its in a heavily nested form component where initial vars get pushed down into the child/grand child level

Comment: What does "kind of push it back into a variable" mean? Also why do you need a ref for this? Setting state should suffice (with or without context, redux, and so on).

Comment: its heavily nested this - I need it come back as a variable - to update a variable -- it can't be used in this manner

Comment: That's not how variables work in JavaScript, nor is it how state works in React. Given you still haven't posted any React code, I can't help beyond this.

Comment: sure - but - can't be used in this reference - needed to come back into the variable

Comment: Here's an example how you might use it with a context in a deeply-nested component: https://codesandbox.io/s/typewriter-kgp08?file=/src/TypewriterInput.js

Comment: sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  async typeAnimation(text, timing, callback) {
    let concatStr = "";
    for (const char of text) {
        concatStr += char;
        await this.sleep(timing);
        callback(concatStr);
    }  
  }
I created something like this